# Crontab failing to run on AWS ec2 Ubuntu Instance

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, cron

Trying to set up a crontab to run a php script on my AWS ec2 ubuntu instance:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/tides/get_tides.php?id=PASSWORD
```

Cannot get it to execute.

The script executes when I run in a web browser:

```
http://URL_NAME/tides/get_tides.php?id=PASSWORD
```

When I run 'which php' on the command line it returns `/usr/bin/php`
Directory/file permissions (tides & get_tides.php): 755

If I run `sudo /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/tides/get_tides.php?id=PASSWORD` on the command line I get: Could not open input file:

```
/var/www/html/tides/get_tides.php?id=PASSWORD
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's no such thing as a query string on the CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by not using absolute paths in my cron scripts:

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$file = "$path/cron-test.txt";
```

I replaced `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` with `/var/www/html`

The crantab command is: `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron-test.php`

Answer (score 1):

There is no directly way to run php scriping with `?id=PASSWORD`, you can adjust the cronjob to run as

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl -o temp.txt http://URL_NAME/tides/get_tides.php?id=PASSWORD
```

or

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O temp.txt http://URL_NAME/tides/get_tides.php?id=PASSWORD
```

Since you didn't show the content in get_tides.php, maybe you can pass command line arguments to a PHP script

```
php /var/www/html/tides/get_tides.php PASSWORD
```

and update the php to :

```
<?php
// $argv[0] is '/var/www/html/tides/get_tides.php'
$id = $argv[1];
?>
```

Comment: I seem to have a few problems here. I have decide to use $argv, but basic scripts are failing to run via cron.
I have been trying to run the following test script:

$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$file = "$path/cron-test.txt";
$data = date("l d M Y: H:i") . "\r\n";

if (($fp = fopen($file, "a")) !== false) {
  fwrite($fp, $data);
  fclose($fp);
}

The script creates the text file if I run via a web browser, but not from the following cron command:
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron-test.php

What am I missing?